# Sufficient $\varepsilon$-$\delta$-criterion for polynomial tail decay

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

While reading a proof of the Bobkov-Houdre conjecture, I stumbled upon the following claim (Step 1 on page 1 of [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1214/ECP.v1-972)):

If for a random variable $X$ and positive $\varepsilon$, $\delta$ there exists positive $t_0$ such that
\begin{equation*}
  P \left( \left| X \right| \geq \left( \sqrt{2} + \varepsilon \right) t \right)
  \leq
  \frac{1}{2-\delta} P \left( \left| X \right| \geq t\right)
\end{equation*}
for $t \geq t_0$, then
\begin{equation*}
  P \left( \left| X \right|  \geq t \right) \leq \frac{C_p}{t^p}
\end{equation*}
for all $p \in (0,2)$.

As this claim is not proved it must be well-known, but unfortunately I was not able to fill in the details. Could somebody please help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix $p\in(0,2)$ and pick $\varepsilon$, $\delta$ small enough such that
$$
\frac{\log(2-\delta)}{\log(\sqrt{2}+\varepsilon)}\ge p.
$$
Now we can apply the assumption $n$ times to get
$$
P(|X|\ge(\sqrt{2}+\varepsilon)^n t_0)\le \frac{1}{(2-\delta)^n}P(|X|>t_0)\le \frac{1}{(2-\delta)^n}\le \frac{1}{(\sqrt{2}+\varepsilon)^{np}},
$$
so that the property is readily verified for $t$ of the form $(\sqrt{2}+\varepsilon)^n t_0$, with $n$ integer. You can then extend the result for all $t$'s using the fact that $P(|X|\ge t)$ is non-increasing.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this elegant argument, and just for completeness and future readers: The argument also shows that the two inside both logarithms can be replaced by any number greater than one and only the square root has to be there (in general, for $p \in (0,r)$, the square root should be replaced by the $r$th root).